# Hide fields in Display Form

Tags: display-form, hidden

I want to hide some fields in my Display Form... I was using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("A[name = 'SPBookmark_Start_x0020_date']").closest("tr").hide();
});
```

But when the page loads, the fields are there.... so the fields are only hidden after javascript executes the code... this is a problem to me... some users CANT see this values...
Is there a way to not load some fields in Display Form?

Comment: From Power Shell Script u can set ShowInDisplayForm Attribute to False.

Comment: u can set it by [SharePoint Manager](http://spm.codeplex.com/) also

Comment: Is the actual requirement that only SOME users can't display the fields? This is a mayor point in the solution we should pursue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simple like this.

```
SPUtility.GetSPField('City').Hide();
```

Please refer [this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/88064/hide-show-field-on-list-form-based-on-value-from-another-field) to show how to apply it.

**Edit:**

As far as you are concerned not only on the displaying and having high security concerns over the security of data, you better try something like creating another list with a one-to-one mapping. Then add a lookup column from first list to the second list and move the secured column from first list to second list. Then you can give a restricted permission on the second list. This will be the option as you cannot use SPD or even InfoPath.

Comment: yes this also hides the field... but the values are still there... if users go to html, he is able to see the values... and I dont want that users be able to see the values...

Comment: So what if user create a personal view with that column in. He can see values of all the list items ryt?

Comment: no, users dont have permitions to create views

Comment: Great then take the table row which includes the field you have, then set the innerHTML to empty. Still if someone use a tool like Fidler, he can see the response body and find the initial HTML sent.

Comment: yes, thats what I want to prevent

Comment: You can try with InfoPath or SPD. But if this is a super secure matter, I would suggest adding another list and set permissions on that as the safest approach even though there is 1 to 1 mapping. Unfortunately SharePoint do not have column based permission setting.

Comment: Unfortunately InfoPath and SPD are disabled here in company =/ could you explain me your suggest?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16843/discussion-between-malin-de-silva-and-thiago).

Comment: You want to have column permissions, but SharePoint does not have column permissions.
Yes you can hide the value, you can hide the row in the Display.aspx, you can do many things. But users could still query the list via REST for example or getting a email notification with all fields...
I think you have to use a second "public" list for the users and synchronize the items via worflows or something.

Answer (score 1):

The answer has already been given.

Either use Powershell to hide the field in Display Form (take a look at another [discussion](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/52642/how-to-set-columns-visible-only-in-display-form-on-a-column-used-by-a-content-ty) for some helpful guidance or at [this page](http://www.n8d.at/blog/hide-fields-from-lists-and-content-types/))

```
#Get the web and site column objects
$web = Get-SPWeb http://site
$column = $web.Fields["Column To hide"]

#Set the PushChangesToLists property for the changes to be applied
#to lists where the column has already been added
$column.PushChangesToLists = $true

#Change the ShowInEditForm and other properties and update objects
$column.ShowInEditForm = $false
$column.ShowInNewForm = $false
$column.ShowInDisplayForm = $true
£column.ShowInViewForms = $true
$column.Update()
$web.Update()
$web.Dispose()
```

Or Use [Sharepoint Manager](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/8553.sharepoint-2010-manager.aspx) which is an essential tool for Sharepoint anyway and since it has a Graphical User Interface it is great for beginners too.