# Hide Doc.Lib column from entering values while uploading a document

Tags: document-library, file-upload, item-added

How can I hide a  form from Displaying a custom field that is created in my document library ? Its a document library  and I am updating this column through *itemadded()* eventreceiver.

My issue is this column - **NPDModifiedBy** will be filled with my code in eventreceiver and should not be from sharepoint UI.
So, i dont want to show this field, when end user uploads the document into my document library

How to hide this doc.lib column while uploading the document upload? [this is not a  site column] 
  [[image: hide-doc-lib]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mG9Sr.png)

Comment: Do you have Powershell access? Or Can we write custom JavaScript for hide particular filed?

Comment: Sam, am in ON-PREM, so have full control on my server ,  have written the code provided by Gautam, am checking now.

Comment: Yes, then It will work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below powershell:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb https://sitecollection
$list = $web.Lists["ListName"]
$column = $list.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("NPDModifiedBy")

#Change the ShowInEditForm and other properties and update objects
$column.ShowInEditForm = $false
$column.ShowInNewForm = $false
$column.ShowInDisplayForm = $false
$column.ShowInViewForms = $false
$column.PushChangesToLists = $true;
$column.Update()
$web.Update()
$web.Dispose()
```

Reference - [Hide column in display form](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/52642/how-to-set-columns-visible-only-in-display-form-on-a-column-used-by-a-content-ty)

[Hide list using powershell](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/29277.sharepoint-2010-hide-list-field-columns-using-powershell.aspx)

Comment: Gautam ,thanks , but when i do this , my custom column is not getting updated by my code. in my ItemAdded() event receiver i am writing the code  by updating this column within the runwithelevatedprivileges

Comment: Thats very strange, this code simply hides the column, have added `$column.PushChangesToLists` line here, but not sure it might help. Can you check ?